# Modal popup extender disappears on gridview refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, gridview

I'm having an update panel which is refreshing the gridview every 2 seconds. I've added modalpopup extender to confirm user action within the gridview. And I've wrapped all other controls in my asp page in another update panel to avoid the page being refreshed everytime.

While I think I'm only refreshing the gridview the whole page is refreshing and the modal popup extender disappear after 2 sec. Please help me with a solution.

**strong text**

This is how my aspx page looks like.

--Mainupdatepanel--
--div--
--table--
--dropdown--
--button--
--textbox--
--/table--
--updatePanel1
--gridview with item template buttons--
--/updatepanel1--
--updatepanel2--
--confirmbuttonextender--
--confirmbuttonextender>
--modalpopup--
--/modalpopup--
--panel--

--buttons -- for modalpopup
--/panel--
--/updatepanel2--
--/div--
--/MainUpdatepanel--

In the code behind:

Timer_click event I've called updatepanel1.update();

In the click events of the button inside gridview I've called updatepanel2.update();

Comment: Please post all relevant code/markup. Update your question to include this information.

Comment: Can you post some code? How are you refreshing the page? You haven't provided enough information to suggest anything that would address your problem directly. I could tell you how to set up your pages to make it work, but I have no idea how you set up your code so my advice might be useless or overly burdensome to you.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow.. Sorry for the messy update. Still dint figure out how to post code! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple update panels on the page and you want them to refresh independently you need to make sure you set the `UpdateMode` property of the update panels to `Conditional`

Also as it seems both update panels are in turn wrapped in a update panel you will need to alter the `ChildrenAsTriggers` property to be false else the mainupdatepanel will update with the inner update panels

Comment: Hello Sam.. Modalpopup issue is resolved when i set ChildrenAsTriggers property to false in my mainupdate panel.. Now when i select my dropdown It's throwing the following Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.

Comment: when i set enableEventValidation=false in my <page> the dropdown selection changed event is not triggering other dropdown to load corresponding data.